# Dropdown changing width as browser gets smaller

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, styles

Everything seems to work fine when the browser size is large... but when the dropdown on the right is open and the user shrinks the browser size... the dropdown on the right changes width and the user image floats from right to left.

I have tried given it a fixed width... it fixed the width but still floats left. Seems to be something with bootstrap not my custom styling

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u553ozvd/1/)**

```css
img.logo {
  margin-top: -12px;
  height: 55px;
}

.navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse li a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.navigation .top-nav a,
.navigation .top-nav .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.user.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.user.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.user.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #282c36;
}

#profile-img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}

.user .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #282c36;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}

.user .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
  height: 50px !important;
  background-color: #282c36 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.user .dropdown-menu li a {
  height: 100% !important;
  background-color: #282c36 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.user .dropdown-menu li:hover,
.user .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #282c36 !important;
  color: white;
}

.navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse>ul>li {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.top-nav .navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.top-nav .navbar-nav>li,
.navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.top-nav .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.top-nav .navbar-right {
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 15px !important;
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .top-nav .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -8px !important;
    right: 15px !important;
  }
  .top-nav .cart a {
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
  .top-nav .user {
    top: 5px;
  }
  .top-nav .cart {
    padding-top: -5px !important;
  }
  .top-nav .user .dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 999 !important;
    background-color: #282c36 !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: -5px;
  }
  .top-nav .navbar-header {
    height: 60px !important;
  }
  .navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse a {
    line-height: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <li class="dropdown user">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://freefacebookhakken.nl/img/profile-pic.png" id="profile-img"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" id="profile-toggle"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Testing </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

First screen shot

[image: First Screenshot]

Second Screen shot

[image: Second Screenshot]

Comment: Could you create snippet or jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: @ovokuro thought I already did that... updated

Comment: @mplungjan updated again

Comment: Please use the snippet editor here so we do not have to go to JSFiddle when not necessary (due to SO sandbox) Just click the `<>` as I just did for you

Comment: the snippet works good. whats the problem?

Comment: @lhavCoder updated with screenshots

Comment: aha. i thought so. u've resized the window to such a small width that it looks like its floating to the left. and thats because your image and drop down have a fixed width.

Comment: i usually dont worry about 100 or 200px width resolutions, because no device is actually that small.

Comment: @lhavCoder the issue starts on a 678px... so much bigger than a small phone

Comment: hmm. when i run your code snippet it seems to work fine at 678px.

Comment: okay i got your questioin. you're saying just the user image shifts from right to left , right?? i just understood your question properly

Comment: yes @lhavCoder and dropdown item text moves a few pixels as well (just a few pixels though)

Answer (score 0):

This css update will fix your width issue.

```
.navbar-right, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu {
  width: 130px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/f62kfx8b/)

Looks like you have a few other issues though (nav bar edges straighten out when short, line appears in nav bar when short, height of drop-down lines change when short).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's navbar classes have media queries that adjust positioning so they integrate with the toggleable mobile navbar. But you aren't using it and the navbar-right class used on the  that the dropdown is in has a media query that adjusts positioning at max width:767px that likely causes the issue you're seeing.

You will have to either change that media query in the bootstrap css file (alternatively add your own css to prevent those media query changes, but may be messy. As an example, I tried in the jsfiddle by adding .user{min-width: 160px;} which partially solved your issue, you'll see what I mean by adding that), or use a dropdown with your own classes (you can easily start with one of [these](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar)).

Comment: I know that its the bootstrap media query but which one is doing it is the issue

Comment: @media (max-width: 767px)
.top-nav .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -8px !important;
    right: 15px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Find the code snippet for your question. Thanks.

```css
.top-nav {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
        }
        
        img.logo {
            margin-top: -12px;
            height: 55px;
        }
        
        .navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse li a {
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        
        .navigation .top-nav a,
        .navigation .top-nav .navbar-nav>li>a {
            color: white;
        }
        
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.user.open>a,
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.user.open>a:hover,
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.user.open>a:focus {
            background-color: #282c36;
        }
        
        #profile-img {
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 3px;
        }
        
        .user .dropdown-menu {
            background-color: #282c36;
            border: 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            min-width: auto !important;
        }
        
        .user .dropdown-menu li {
            padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
            margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
            height: 50px !important;
            background-color: #282c36 !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        
        .user .dropdown-menu li a {
            height: 100% !important;
            background-color: #282c36 !important;
            color: white !important;
        }
        
        .user .dropdown-menu li:hover,
        .user .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #282c36 !important;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse>ul>li {
            padding-left: 8px;
        }
        
        .top-nav .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: block!important;
        }
        
        .top-nav .navbar-nav>li,
        .navbar-nav {
            float: left !important;
        }
        
        .top-nav .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
            margin-right: -15px !important;
        }
        
        .top-nav .navbar-right {
            position: absolute !important;
            right: 15px !important;
        }
        
        @media(max-width: 767px) {
            .navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse {
                height: 60px;
            }
            .top-nav .navbar-right {
                float: right !important;
                position: absolute !important;
                top: -8px !important;
                right: 15px !important;
            }
            .top-nav .cart a {
                margin-top: 6px;
            }
            .top-nav .user {
                top: 5px;
            }
            .top-nav .cart {
                padding-top: -5px !important;
            }
            .top-nav .user .dropdown-menu {
                z-index: 999 !important;
                background-color: #282c36 !important;
                position: relative !important;
                top: 50px;
            }
            .top-nav .navbar-header {
                height: 60px !important;
            }
            .navigation .top-nav .navbar-inverse a {
                line-height: 30px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="top-nav">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown user">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://freefacebookhakken.nl/img/profile-pic.png" id="profile-img"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" id="profile-toggle"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Testing </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```